# Calculate number of days from a date before 1900

Tags: excel, vba, date

To calculate the number of days from a date before 1900, I have to use this formula which adds 1000 years

```
=IF(ISTEXT(M3),DATEVALUE(LEFT(M3,LEN(M3)-4)&RIGHT(M3,4)+1000),EDATE(M3,12000))
```

since this formula has added 1000 year, then I have to deduct 1000 from the result to get the final correct result

For example: 12 Jan 1892 -> 12 Jan 2892 (added 1000 years)

Then from this new date (12 Jan 2892), I can use to add any number of days to get another new date for my purpose, let say I wanted to add 5626 days then I get 9 June 2907, then to get the correct result I have to deduct 1000 years from that which I have 9 June 1907

however, let say another example where I add a less number of days, e.g. 2813 days to 12 Jan 2892, then I got 25 Sept 2899. In order to get the correct result, i need to deduct 1000 years, which excel give 25 Sept 3799. which is not correct, the correct is 25 Sept 1899. So how do I display this correct result?

Comment: Why the requirement  to add 1000 years when the VBA  data type Date can handle  dates ranging from January 1, 100 to December 31, 9999 [Data type summary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary)

Comment: Should be able to use DateSerial and DateAdd to accomplish your requirements eg DateAdd("d", 5626, DateSerial(1892, 1, 12))  ,   DateAdd("d", 2813, DateSerial(1892, 1, 12))  possible dont require DateSerial is already have the dates in the spreadsheet.

Comment: I can use your formula DateAdd("d", 2813, DateSerial(1892, 1, 12) to Debug.Print ok no problem, but to output in a cell for example : Sheet1.cells(1,1)= DateAdd("d", 2813, DateSerial(1892, 1, 12) then it doesn't work. it gives error "application defined or object defined error

Comment: Just a reminder: not every year in the span of a 1000 years has the same number of days as any other year. You have leap days every 4 years (and that's basic) except you don't have them on years multiple of 100, except you do have them on multiple of 400. Also don't forget days that did not exists (like from october the 5th to the 14th 1582) and (might also be important) not every country switched to the Gregorian calendar at the same time.

Comment: So, for example, the number of days from 2100 to 1900 will be different from the number of days from 3100 to 1900 because the year 3000 won't have a leap day while the year 2000 will have it.

Comment: From memory possible issue with leap days I think for the year 1900.  I could an very old issue that was addressed.  Make  sure to double check result and  test just incase.

Comment: If need more advanced Date calculations with different calenders etc. I  have recently done  COM wrappers for .Net DateTime etc which is on  Github.  Would require creating a function to present the output as a VBA Date in a cell.  Assuming below the DateAdd handles leap years etc thou not thoughly tested.

Comment: I'm totally aware of the leap year and the different number of days but there seems no other way to work around because excel don't allow display year before 1900.

Comment: with the solution of Johnstone, I can display the result via Debug.Print , but it is not possible to display on excel sheet, again ,excel don't allow to display any year calculation that is before 1900, so I'm still stuck

Comment: @AlanWong The date befoe 1900 will displayed in dd/mm/yyyy format  thou appears formatting issue formatting Dates before 1900 using anyt other Date forrmat.  Will testing formatting using my .Net wrapper library.

Comment: @AlanWong Appears also issues using DateAdd with Dates before  1900 providing incorrect results will have to investigate exactly why.  Probably due to the Date which is in double  format are negative values.

Answer (score 1):

This VBA function is somewhat restrictive in that the pre-1900 dates **must** be entered in `yyyy-m-d` format and the `date` argument in the function is assumed to be a Range reference. If necessary, it could be expanded to accept other formats, inputs, or even detect the format.

If you enter the invalid date `29-Feb-1900` on the Excel sheet, it will interpret that as `1-Mar-1900` but that behavior could be changed to flag it as an invalid input.

```
Option Explicit
'pre=1900 dates must be entered as yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy-m-d
'Cells must be custom formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd`
'Function accepts only range reference for the date argument
Function vbaAddDays(dt As Range, dys) As Variant
    Dim myDT As Date, vDT As Variant
    Dim sep As String
    
'could test for sep, but for now will leave it as hyphen
'and assume format is `yyyy=mm-dd` if pre=1900
sep = "-"

Select Case TypeName(dt.Value) 'could be String,Double or date
    Case "Date"
        vDT = Split(dt.Text, sep)
    Case "String"
        vDT = Split(dt.Value, sep)
    Case "Double"
        vDT = Split(Format(CDate(dt.Value), "yyyy-mm-dd"), sep)
    Case Else
        MsgBox "something wrong"
End Select

myDT = DateSerial(vDT(0), vDT(1), vDT(2))

vbaAddDays = Format(myDT + dys, "yyyy-mm-dd")
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, short & helpful, especially mentioning the need of range cell formatting to "yyyy-m-d" and the non-existing date 1900-02-29 :+) *Another challenge would be to code how to get correct workdays between the first quarter of 1900 and before in gregorian calendar.*

Comment: @T.M. That might or might not be a challenge since, back then, my understanding is that six and seven day workweeks were common. (-:

Comment: Ty for responding - please excuse typo :-; meant a clarification getting **week**days (Sunday, Monday ...) in first quarter and before in light of the historical Excel error; basically applying a day-date format upon `DateSerial` is/should be the way

Comment: @T.M. I'm sure you can solve your problem using the same principles shown in this post. Ask a new question with details if you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to add days to a date.

```
Public Function DateAddDays(ByVal inputDate As Date, ByVal numberOfDays As Long) As Date
    DateAddDays = DateAdd("d", numberOfDays, inputDate)
End Function
```

In the spreadsheet where InputDate is a named cell containing 1/12/1892 i.e. Jan 12, 1892

Note Culture I'm using English (Aus) so the date display default is dd/mm/yyyy and may vary according to culture used or cell format etc.

Eg.
Formula in a cell where B2 contains the number of days to add.
= DateAddDays(InputDate,B2) i.e. = DateAddDays(1/12/1892,5626) = 28/04/1908

```
Add Days     Output
5626         28/04/1908
2813         15/08/1900
```

Appears issue formating dates before 1900 in any other Date format.  Using my [VBA-DotNetLib](https://github.com/MarkJohnstoneGitHub/VBA-DotNetLib) could do the following. To use requires registering the type library and importing the VBA classes. **It's a work in progress.**

To avoid  issues with VBA Date i.e. leap year issue for 1900 etc input dates are formatted as **text** not date format. So parsing the date text input is parsed according to the Culture settings.  Could adapt the function to pass in required culture.

Using DotNetLib type library create function below.

```
Public Function FormatDateAddDays(ByVal inputDate As String, ByVal numberOfDays As Long, ByVal dateFormat As String) As String
    Dim date1 As DotNetLib.DateTime
    Set date1 = DateTime.Parse(inputDate)
    Dim result As DotNetLib.DateTime
    Set result = date1.AddDays(numberOfDays)
    FormatDateAddDays = result.ToString2(dateFormat)
End Function
```

Formula in a cell =FormatDateAddDays(A3,B3,"d MMM yyyy")
where column A is text input Date eg 12/1/1792 (Jan 1 1792), column B is days to add eg. 5626

```
Input Date  Add Days Output
2/1/1792    5626     9 Jun 1807
12/1/1792   2813    25 Sep 1799
12/1/1892   5626     9 Jun 1907
12/1/1892   2813    25 Sep 1899
12/1/1892   500     26 May 1893
28/02/1900  1        1 Mar 1900
1/12/1899   1        2 Dec 1899
2/12/1899   1        3 Dec 1899
3/12/1899   1        4 Dec 1899
4/12/1899   1        5 Dec 1899
5/12/1899   1        6 Dec 1899
6/12/1899   1        7 Dec 1899
7/12/1899   1        8 Dec 1899
8/12/1899   1        9 Dec 1899
9/12/1899   1       10 Dec 1899
10/12/1899  1       11 Dec 1899
11/12/1899  1       12 Dec 1899
12/12/1899  1       13 Dec 1899
13/12/1899  1       14 Dec 1899
14/12/1899  1       15 Dec 1899
15/12/1899  1       16 Dec 1899
16/12/1899  1       17 Dec 1899
17/12/1899  1       18 Dec 1899
18/12/1899  1       19 Dec 1899
19/12/1899  1       20 Dec 1899
20/12/1899  1       21 Dec 1899
21/12/1899  1       22 Dec 1899
22/12/1899  1       23 Dec 1899
23/12/1899  1       24 Dec 1899
24/12/1899  1       25 Dec 1899
25/12/1899  1       26 Dec 1899
26/12/1899  1       27 Dec 1899
27/12/1899  1       28 Dec 1899
28/12/1899  1       29 Dec 1899
29/12/1899  1       30 Dec 1899
30/12/1899  1       31 Dec 1899
31/12/1899  1        1 Jan 1900
1/01/1900   1        2 Jan 1900
2/01/1900   1        3 Jan 1900
3/01/1900   1        4 Jan 1900
4/01/1900   1        5 Jan 1900
5/01/1900   1        6 Jan 1900
6/01/1900   1        7 Jan 1900
7/01/1900   1        8 Jan 1900
8/01/1900   1        9 Jan 1900
9/01/1900   1       10 Jan 1900
10/01/1900  1       11 Jan 1900
11/01/1900  1       12 Jan 1900
12/01/1900  1       13 Jan 1900
13/01/1900  1       14 Jan 1900
14/01/1900  1       15 Jan 1900
15/01/1900  1       16 Jan 1900
16/01/1900  1       17 Jan 1900
17/01/1900  1       18 Jan 1900
18/01/1900  1       19 Jan 1900
19/01/1900  1       20 Jan 1900
20/01/1900  1       21 Jan 1900
21/01/1900  1       22 Jan 1900
22/01/1900  1       23 Jan 1900
23/01/1900  1       24 Jan 1900
24/01/1900  1       25 Jan 1900
25/01/1900  1       26 Jan 1900
26/01/1900  1       27 Jan 1900
27/01/1900  1       28 Jan 1900
28/01/1900  1       29 Jan 1900
29/01/1900  1       30 Jan 1900
30/01/1900  1       31 Jan 1900
31/01/1900  1        1 Feb 1900
1/02/1900   1        2 Feb 1900
2/02/1900   1        3 Feb 1900
3/02/1900   1        4 Feb 1900
4/02/1900   1        5 Feb 1900
5/02/1900   1        6 Feb 1900
6/02/1900   1        7 Feb 1900
7/02/1900   1        8 Feb 1900
8/02/1900   1        9 Feb 1900
9/02/1900   1       10 Feb 1900
10/02/1900  1       11 Feb 1900
11/02/1900  1       12 Feb 1900
12/02/1900  1       13 Feb 1900
13/02/1900  1       14 Feb 1900
14/02/1900  1       15 Feb 1900
15/02/1900  1       16 Feb 1900
16/02/1900  1       17 Feb 1900
17/02/1900  1       18 Feb 1900
18/02/1900  1       19 Feb 1900
19/02/1900  1       20 Feb 1900
20/02/1900  1       21 Feb 1900
21/02/1900  1       22 Feb 1900
22/02/1900  1       23 Feb 1900
23/02/1900  1       24 Feb 1900
24/02/1900  1       25 Feb 1900
25/02/1900  1       26 Feb 1900
26/02/1900  1       27 Feb 1900
27/02/1900  1       28 Feb 1900
28/02/1900  1        1 Mar 1900 *Adding one day to Feb 1900  is  Mar 1 as expected.
29/02/1900  1       #VALUE!     *Note 29 Feb 1900 is an invalid date as 1900 is not a leap year
1/03/1900   1       2 Mar 1900
2/03/1900   1       3 Mar 1900
3/03/1900   1       4 Mar 1900
4/03/1900   1       5 Mar 1900
5/03/1900   1       6 Mar 1900
6/03/1900   1       7 Mar 1900
7/03/1900   1       8 Mar 1900
```

Or could develop your own custom Date formating in VBA breaking down the various Date components, i.e. would require obtain day of week, month name etc.

Comment: the result you display only works for year after 1900, to make the example clearer, let say I add 2000 days or less from Jan 12,1892, then the correct output should be before 1900,.

Comment: For example, I would add 500 days to Jan, 12, 1892 and the output result would be May, 26,1893

Comment: I use this online calculator to check https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/time/days-from.php

Comment: @AlanWong From brief testing dates before 1900 will display with the default Date format any other date format appears an issue.  If  wish format the Date differently possible create a custom DateFormat function  or have done String.Format .net wrapper eg. FormatDate = VBAString.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", inputDate) converts  1/12/1892 to Tuesday, January 12, 1892.  If doing soley in VBA should be able to use various Date functions breaking down each  compoent.  [VBA-DotNetLib](https://github.com/MarkJohnstoneGitHub/VBA-DotNetLib)

Comment: @M.Johnstone Does your code and dotnetlib handle the 1900 leap year issue and the fact that dates during the first 60 days of 1900 are represented by a different serial number in Excel vs VBA?  What does it show with, for example, `1899-Mar-1` and `365` days?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  There shouldn't  any issues as it's wrappers of various  .Net Framework classees.   Static/Singleton members are wrapped in a VBA singleton class eg DateTime and the instance DotNetLib.DateTime. Modifications for naming with the API i.e. the factory methods for DateTime use a variety of unique names for the constructor overloads.   To format the datatype VBAStrings.Format  
 or Strings.Format overloads.  Plenty of DateTime examples  [DateTime](https://github.com/MarkJohnstoneGitHub/VBA-DotNetLib/tree/main/VBA/Examples/System/DateTime)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  Testing with the OP question appears good, thou should do some unit tests to confirm.   For DateTime classes etc I haven't yet implemented  the  IConvertible interface.  To use the DotNetLib.tlb will need to register the type library first, instructions on  the main page.  Work in  progress so modifications to API may occur and regularily updated so will require  to unregister and register again when updating.   Overall the type library should appear similar to C# .Net Framework with modifications due to naming of overloads or VBA reserved words.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Updated the function to parse the input date  as  text to avoid any VBA Date conversion issues. Tested for VBA Date  1900 leap year issue.   Could possible change the to use DateTime.TryParse instead of  Parse and could adapt to add a required culture which would allow parsing text Dates for other regions. i.e.  The example is Eng(Aus) so  dates  are  dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Where do you get DotNetLib , I copy the function and it sent the error" user defined type not defined", seem like i'm missing some sort of libraries

Comment: @M.Johnstone I think you would also need to return the output date as text (if it is before `1-Mar-1900`).

Comment: @ RonRosenfeld The  output date is in example is text.  Alternatively possibly use the .Net DateTime.Ticks or DateTime.ToBinary() to return a longlong.  Thou probably only any  use with .Net DateTime members.  i.e. You can create a DateTime from a longlong i.e. Ticks using the VBA DateTime.CreateFromTicks factory method.